# can you set up fields to count like you can in an access query?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is how I can count a field called TotalCompleted in Access,

```
TotalCompleted: IIf([dod] Between forms!frmMonthlyReports!BeginningDate And 
forms!frmMonthlyReports!EndingDate 
And ([DischargeInformation] Like "completed*" 
Or [DischgInfo] Like "completed*"),1,0)
```

then I just count all the ones to get my total

Can I do this some way in Crystal Reports, can you show me an example?

Comment: why not write SQL to do this and then show the value on your report.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed. Create a new formula along the lines of:

```
if {yourtable.dod} in {?FromData} to {?ToDate} and {yourtable.dischargeinformation} LIKE 'completed*' then
 1
else if {yourtable.dischginfo} LIKE 'completed*' then
 1
else
 0
```

Comment: +1 You should probably mention that you need to insert a sum of your formula to get the total.